# How to set Environment Variables on EC2(window) instance via User Data

Tags: aws-ec2-instance-connect

```xml
<powershell>
$file = $env:SystemRoot + "\Temp\" + (Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd-yy-hh-mm")
New-Item $file -ItemType file
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

I did not achieve the expected results using the above code.
The expected file was not generated under this path `C:\Windows\Temp\` in the instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instance needs to install EC2Launch,and here is the Revised code：

`<powershell> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force $file = $env:SystemRoot + "\Temp\" + (Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd-yy-hh-mm") New-Item $file -ItemType file </powershell> <persist>true</persist>`